# Why can't I use "\1" when I try to replace something with regular expression in text editor?

Tags: regex

I have a text file that contains many numbers with quotation marks around them, and I want to remove all the quotation marks.

I tried this in Visual Studio's editor, EmEditor and Notepad++, and I just couldn't have it done.

In the the find box, I put in

```
"[0-9]+"
```

and in the replace box, I put in

```
\1
```

or

```
$1
```

All three editors could correctly find all those numbers with quotation marks, but failed to replace them with none quotation marks version. They just delete the original numbers, or replace them with "$1" literally.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html  http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the number matching in parentheses to create a capture group and you should be able to replace it with $1:

```
"([0-9]+)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I found the answer.

find (")([0-9]+)(")

and replace with \2